# generate_series in postgresql from field in table

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql!

I have a table "meeting"

```
create table meeting (
id SERIAL, 
name varchar, 
date_start timestamp not null, 
period interval default '0:0:0');
```

And some data

```
select * from meeting;
+----+---------------+---------------------+--------+
| id |     name      |     date_start      | period |
+----+---------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | Måndagsmöte   | 2017-06-06 09:00:00 | 7 days |
|  2 | torsdagssoppa | 2017-06-01 00:00:00 | 7 days |
+----+---------------+---------------------+--------+
```

And can select comming meetings from this;

```
select id,name, date from meeting,
generate_series( 
(select date_start::timestamptz from meeting where id=1)::timestamp,
'2017-08-01 00:00:00', (select period from meeting where id=1)) as date
 where date > '2017-06-15 00:00:00' 
 and date < '2017-07-20 00:00:00' and id=1;

+----+-------------+---------------------+
| id |    name     |        date         |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-06-20 09:00:00 |
|  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-06-27 09:00:00 |
|  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-07-04 09:00:00 |
|  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-07-11 09:00:00 |
|  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-07-18 09:00:00 |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

Is there any posibility to relax the "id=1" and have all meetings for all names?

/gh

Answer (score 0):

According to your data you can use the next query:

> ```
> select *
> from (select id,
>              name, 
>              generate_series(date_start, '2017-08-01 00:00:00', period) date
>       from   meeting) mt
> where  mt.date > '2017-06-15 00:00:00' 
> and    mt.date < '2017-07-20 00:00:00'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name          | date               
> -: | :------------ | :------------------
>  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-06-20 09:00:00
>  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-06-27 09:00:00
>  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-07-04 09:00:00
>  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-07-11 09:00:00
>  1 | Måndagsmöte | 2017-07-18 09:00:00
>  2 | torsdagssoppa | 2017-06-22 00:00:00
>  2 | torsdagssoppa | 2017-06-29 00:00:00
>  2 | torsdagssoppa | 2017-07-06 00:00:00
>  2 | torsdagssoppa | 2017-07-13 00:00:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=57019467d1dc604ed25b59808b2d180a)*